# Store XML to Mysql

Tags: xml

I need to store XML(Rss feed) to mysql. How to store with out duplicate ? How to check them please help me for this.

Thank you.

Comment: duplicate entry? or duplicate feed?

Comment: duplicate entry in old feed.

ex. I execute page 1 time data will stored 10 row in my database then next time the feed have new update only 2 news how to insert only the last 2 news to database.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'your file path' INTO TABLE yourSchema.yourTable rows identified by '<name_the_tag>';
```

If you have already set the columns correctly, this will not make the rows duplicate.